# Push Notification isn't working in Android, codename one

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-play-services, codenameone

I'm failing in implementing Push Notification in Codename One, Android.

It seems registering push works perfectly now as follow, because `public void registeredForPush(String deviceId)` method of `PushCallback` interface is called successfully.

```
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() ->  Display.getInstance().registerPush());
```

But, it seems server doesn't work.

```
new Push(PUSH_TOKEN, "Hello World", deviceId)
            .gcmAuth(GCM_SERVER_API_KEY)
            .send();
```

Above, `deviceId` is from the Android Phone itself, that is, app works as Push notification server as well as client.
I think this code should push notification to the phone itself.

Of course, I followed the guide [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html#push-bureaucracy-android-section).

I also turned on Notification of this app in Phone settings and my codename one account plan is pro, but I don't know why notification arrived to my Android Phone.

Please help me with this issue.

(NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201705191307)

Codename One Version: 3.7.1)

Comment: Does the device id start with cn1-gcm? Do you see print outs to the console? When you run this in the simulator with the network monitor open what do you see for the server request response?

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I found the reason so simple and fixed it. I will post it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the reason is.
First of all, I had to use `Push.getPushKey()` method to get phone's device id`.
But I had managed phones device ID as follows:

```
public void registeredForPush(String deviceId) {
        store(deviceId); //this should be store(Push.getPushKey()); instead.
}
```

But it was absolutely wrong.
As Shai said in comment, the device id for pushing notification should be start `'cn1-gcm'`, but here `deviceId` was not so.
I'm just confused why `registeredForPush()` method has `devieId` as its parameter, which makes developers confusing.

Anyway, it works perfectly now while I'm using `Push.getPushKey()` in my code.
I'm very happy now and thanks to Shai and all of Codename One.